# Cannot access partial C drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

So, i am a complete retard when it comes to computers, and i could desperately need some help. 
Last week, my win10 laptop had some error on startup, and apparently the only option would be to reset the whole thing and lose all my data. DEFINITELY not possible as i have no backup of my files. So a friend recommended i use Ubuntu to access my files, and then reset win10. 
Problem is, i am using a CD to temporarily access the files without installing Ubuntu 14.04. Now, i can access the D drive, and transfer all data to external HDD, but there is no C drive. There is something called "OS" which shows **partial** C drive, and i can't figure out why. Some of the pictures from my C drive appear on that, but nothing of the important stuff that i need :( 
Please help, as i am applying for masters soon, and i have a lot of data on my C drive. 
And i am a real noob about stuff like this. I hope i have not lost the data? As i can still access some files of the C drive.

Output of `lsblk -f`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk -f 
NAME FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT 
sda 
├─sda1 
├─sda2 /media/ubuntu/Recovery 
├─sda3 
├─sda4 /media/ubuntu/OS 
├─sda5 /media/ubuntu/16C264A6C2648C35 
├─sda6 /media/ubuntu/DATA 
└─sda7
sdb 
├─sdb1 
└─sdb2 
sr0 
iso9660 Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS amd64 /cdrom 
loop0 /rofs
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31407/discussion-on-question-by-prithvi92-cannot-access-partial-c-drive).

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: As there were too many comments to the OP, thus this answer.**

1. Open Grsync from Dash.
2. Navigate to the folder you want to copy from (highlighted):

[image: 1]

3. Navigate to the folder you want to copy to (highlighted):

[image: 2]

4. Then, click the "gear" icon on the top left beside "i" icon.

A new window will open and if there are any errors it will be shown there. Tell us the error that you receive there.